# Questions about using Nuxt's privateRuntimeConfig variables outside of regular components/plugins

Tags: environment-variables, nuxt.js

I have a script in my NuxtJS app, server/index.js, and I'd like to access a private runtime variable in it: apiUrl. The apiUrl comes from a .env file, which is imported in nuxt.config.js under privateRuntimeConfig. Because this .js file isn't a component or anything, $config and context appear to be unavailable. However, I can still access process.env from this file (coming directly from .env). This .js file is exported as a module for use elsewhere in the app.

Here are my questions:

1. Is there any way to call the privateRuntimeConfig variables from a script like this? I know it's running server-side.
2. Is there even any point to doing so? The process.env.apiURl variable is already available in this script. So do I even need to use privateRuntimeConfig for the variable?
3. If I can access the apiUrl from process.env, what is the point of privateRuntimeConfig at all? Is using process.env less secure?

Comment: Maybe give a read to this one: https://nuxtjs.org/tutorials/moving-from-nuxtjs-dotenv-to-runtime-config

Comment: @kissu this answered all of my questions except the first: how can I use the privateRuntimeConfig in a helpers .js file that isn't a component, plugin, or part of the store? It's just a .js file that gets imported.

Comment: I guess that since this one will be out of the Vue context, rather use the usual `dotenv` way.

Comment: @kissu are there any security concerns with just grabbing the variable from process.env?  This is basically what question #3 is asking. If I can just grab the variable from process.env then why bother with privateRuntimeConfig at all?